# Local variable and instance variable has the same name

Tags: java

I dont understand exactly the process that happened in this case:

```
class SomeClass {

    int val = 50;
    String str = "default";

 public SomeClass(int val) {
        val = val;
    }
}
```

what exactly happen in this statement val = val ?

Comment: Arguments shadow members, so this is equivalent to `public SomeClass(int othername) { othername = othername; }` and doesn't touch `this.val` in any way

Comment: That statement does nothing. If you found this code somewhere, it is wrong. Inside the method, `val` refers to the parameter. What you probably want is `this.val = val;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code, as shown, is wrong. The intent here is to assign the value of *local variable* `val` to the *instance variable* `val`. However, without a qualifier, this code just reassigns the local variable to itself. You’ll see it if you add a `final` to the constructor parameter.
What you want is `this.val = val`. It’s common practice to name both the same for legibility, but qualify the instance variable with `this`.
You also want a basic Java book.

Comment: i think it isnt wrong but useless, it was a tricky question that has multiple constructor invoked each others, but i think i got it now, thank u.

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly happen in this statement val = val ?

This assigns the value of the local variable `val` to itself. To assign the local `val` to the instance `val`, use the `this` keyword:

```
this.val = val;
```